# how to handle multiple views in RecyclerView adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

the problem that I implement a ReyclerView with a custom ItemClickListener inside the adapter:

```
    public interface ItemClickListener{
    
            void onItemClick(BookModel book);
        }
```

and here is the whole code (for Adapter):

```
package com.example.recyclerview;

import android.media.Image;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BookAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookAdapter.BookViewHolder> {
  private BookModel[] booklist;
  ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public BookAdapter(BookModel[] booklist, ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.booklist = booklist;
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BookViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new BookViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BookViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bookTitle.setText(booklist[position].getBookName());
        holder.bookAuthor.setText(booklist[position].getBookAuthor());
        holder.bookDescription.setText(booklist[position].getDescription());
        holder.img.setImageResource(booklist[position].getImgId());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view ->{
            itemClickListener.onItemClick(booklist[position]);
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return booklist.length;
    }
    public interface ItemClickListener{

        void onItemClick(BookModel book);
    }


    public class BookViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView bookTitle;
        TextView bookAuthor;
        TextView bookDescription;
        ImageView img;

        public BookViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            bookTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookTitle);
            bookAuthor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookAuthor);
            bookDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookDesc);
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        }
    }
}
```

so the problem that when I have overridden the ItemClickListener inside the activity to control the views inside the list-item( I will attach the code of the activity and the layout below):

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.recyclerview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   // public  boolean flag = false;
   final boolean[] flag = {false};
    BookModel[] bookModels = new BookModel[]{
      new BookModel("مت فارغاً","تود هنري","إن كتاب مت فارغًا هو أداة للأشخاص الذين لا يرغبون في تأجيل أهم أعمالهم - ولا يقصد هنا العمل الوظيفي بل عمل حياتك القابع بداخلك -\n" +
              " إلى الغد. ويعدد تود هنري الأشياء التي تبقينا في حالة رجوع، ثم يفصل كيفية التخلص منها وغرس ممارسات ثابتة في حياتنا تجعلنا نسير على الدرب الصحيح ونفرغ أسمى ما فينا.\n",R.drawable.dieempty),
            new BookModel("الهدوء","سوزان كين","\n" +
                    "يناقش كتاب الهدوء الشخصية الانطوائية بكل شغف بل ويسبر غورها فهو ملىء بقصص لا تنسى لأناس من الواقع،\n" +
                    " ويبين أيضاً إلى أي مدى نبخس الشخصية الانطوائية حقها على نحو لافت وكم نخسر من جراء ذلك.\n" +
                    "فهذا الكتاب الرائع جدير بأن يغير الطريقة التي نرى بها الانطوائيين وكذلك الطريقة التي يرى بها الانطوائيون أنفسهم على حد سواء.\n",R.drawable.quiet),
            new BookModel("شيفرة بلال","د.أحمد خيري العمري","\n" +
                    "أن تتأثر بقصة بلال بن رباح شيء ، ولكن أن تتغير حياتك كلها بسبب ذلك شيء آخر تماما..\n" +
                    "وأن يحدث ذلك في مجتمع عربي مسلم شيء ، ولكن أن يحدث في نيويورك؟!!\n" +
                    "وأن يحدث ذلك في مجتمع عربي مسلم شيء ، ولكن أن يحدث في نيويورك؟!!\n" +
                    "لكن، ذات يوم ..يصل إيميل لأحدهم..، ويتغير كل شيء...\n" +
                    "هذه الرواية هي قصة ما حدث معهم..بسبب (بلال)..\n" +
                    "وما يمكن أن يحدث معك...\n" +
                    "\n",R.drawable.belal),
            new BookModel("من الذي حرك قطعة الجبن الخاصة بي؟","سبنسر جونسون","\n" +
                    "يهدف الكاتب من هذا العمل تجسيد واقع الحياة الذي نعيشها،\n" +
                    " على أسلوب الرمز فرمز إلى متطلبات الحياة وملذاتها بقطعة الجبنة\n" +
                    "، ورمز إلى الحياة التي نعشها والأماكن التي نوجد بها بالممارات العمل تجسيد للواقع الذي نعيش فيه\n" +
                    "، وأراد الكاتب أن يوضح من خلال هذا العمل التغير الذي يحدث داخل متاهة صغيرة، \n" +
                    " يوجد بداخلها أربعة أشخاص هدفهم الأسمى في الوجود هو الحصول على قطعة \"الجبنة\"\n" +
                    " والتي شبهها الكاتب ب\"الرمز أو الهدف\" الذي نسعى في حياتنا الحصول عليه متمثلة في ملذات الحياة مثل\" الصحة،\n" +
                    " المال، اقامة علاقات، الحصول على وظيفة.......وغيرها من ملذات الدنيا، \n" +
                    "فالكل يسعى جاهدا لتحقيق هدفه وإكمال سعادته في الحصول على قطعة الجبن حيث يمثل\n" +
                    " لهم امتلاكها السعادة باكملها، وعدم الحصول عليها يسبب الآلام وعدم السعادة.\n",R.drawable.chess),
            new BookModel("الخيمائي","باولو كويلو","\n" +
                    "الخيميائي هي الرواية الثانية التي كتبها باولو كويليو، والتي حققت نجاحاً عالمياً باهراً، جعل كاتبها من \n" +
                    "أشهر الكتاب العالميين. تتحدث الرواية عن راع أندلسي شاب يدعى سانتياغو. مضى للبحث عن حلمه المتمثل بكنزٍ مدفون قرب أهرامات مصر، بدأت رحلته من\n" +
                    " أسبانيا عندما إلتقى الملك \"ملكي صادق\" الذي أخبره عن الكنز، عَبَرَ مضيق جبل طارق ماراً بالمغرب حتى بلغ مصر، وكانت توجهه طوال الرحلة إشارات غيبية.\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "وفي طريقه للعثور على كنزه الحلم، أحداث كثيرة تقع، كل حدث منها استحال عقبة تكاد تمنعه من متابعة رحلته، إلى أن يجد الوسيلة التي تساعده على تجاوز هذه العقبة....\n" +
                    "وهكذا تتلخص الفكرة لهذه الرواية بجملة قالها الملك لسانتياغو :\"إذا رغبت في شيء.. فإن العالم كله يطاوعك لتحقيق رغبتك\".",R.drawable.alchemist)
    };
    BookAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


        adapter = new BookAdapter(bookModels, new BookAdapter.ItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(BookModel book) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "the item -> "+book.getBookName()+" is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                ImageView favIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.favIcon);

                favIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if(flag[0] == false){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"flag --> "+ flag[0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            favIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_red);
                            flag[0] = true;
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"flag --> "+ flag[0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            favIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav2);
                            flag[0] = false;
                        }
                    }
                });









            }
        });
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



    }
}
```

***list_item.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="15dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">






        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bookTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Book title"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bookAuthor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Book's author"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bookDesc"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is the supporting text This is the supporting text This is the supporting text This is the supporting text This is the supporting text This is the supporting text"
                android:textSize="15dp"/>


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/book"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_margin="20dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/read"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/favIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/fav2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_download"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            

        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

the problem when I clicked the ImageView (favIcon), it's not enabled directly!
which the onItemClick for(ItemClickListener) interface executed first, then
the onClick for the nested onClickListener(favIcon) executed -I have to make a double click to enable the red favIcon, so there is a way that I can control multiple views inside the list_item  without using nested Listener?

***here is a snapshot of my app:***

[image]

***the result after double click***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your ItemClickListener to get what is being clicked and perform action related to it. Just changed your ItemClickListener to following:

```
public interface ItemClickListener{

    void onItemClick(String type, BookModel book);
}
```

Now add click listener to all the views you require for your item. Eg. for you favIcon you can send type=fav, for your download icon type=download, etc.

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view ->{
        itemClickListener.onItemClick("item", booklist[position]);
    });
 holder.favIcon.setOnClickListener(view ->{
        itemClickListener.onItemClick("fav", booklist[position]);
    });
```

Now just use switch case using type and handle your click.

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(String type, BookModel book) {
            switch(type){
                "fav" : //Your Fav handling here
                      break;
                "download" : //Your download handling here
                      break;
                "item" : //Your item click handling here
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it's given me the same result, so I think in a different way - I just made a small change to **your code>>>**

 `holder.favIcon.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            itemClickListener.onItemClick(booklist[position]);
            if(!flag){
                favIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_red);
                flag = true;
            }else{
                favIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav2);
                flag = false; }});
`
In this way, I don't need to handle the view inside MainActivity - and the click will be abled directly 

Comment: Your adding of `favIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}` inside `onItemClick` callback is wrong. As I mentioned you need all click listener in your adapter and pass what viewType has been clicked alongwith the Item data. Also using flag to check if item is favourite or not is wrong as flag is your common variable so for next item click it will deem it as already favourite and you will click it twice to make it favourite. Add favourite flag in your BookModel.